# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() for value of array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am getting the following error:

The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

For the following code:

```
for index, value in enumerate(archList):
  if value > rIntTemp:
    print(index)
```

Any idea how to fix this? the value of archList should not be an array.

Comment: What's the structure of archList and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi Jonathon, given that snippet we're unable to answer your question. Are you able to provide us with a more complete piece of code so we can see what archList and rIntTemp are? In the meantime, try putting print(value) before your if statement so you can see what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have found the issue. rIntTemp is equal to a function return. The function returns x, y so rIntTemp was the array.

My mistake!

Answer (score 0):

`value > rIntTemp` is producing an array like `array([True, False])`. I can think of at least six different functions that could reduce this to a single Boolean value:

1. `lambda a: True`
2. `lambda a: False`
3. `lambda a: a[0]`
4. `lambda a: a[1]`
5. `lambda a: a[0] and a[1]`
6. `lambda a: a[0] or a[1]`

(There are more; I didn't bother getting into ones that use `not`.)

So which one should numpy use? It chooses to use *none* of them, instead requiring you to be explicit about which condition you want. #5 is `a.all()`. #6 is `a.any()`.